# how to pass values in ajax without data

Tags: json, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:'userfeed',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{ans,udata},
    success:function(data){
    $("#container").prepend("<div>"+data+"</div>");
    $("#textarea").val("");
}
```

In above code i used data attribute to get values .My question is how to pass values in ajax without data attriute?

Comment: The data in data:{ans,udata} and success:function(data) are different. You want to pass data without using data attribute. Can you explain further?

Comment: The data in the succes function is the response on the ajax request.